# Giving Custom to?

Tags: phrases, expressions

A rather old-fashioned farewell after visiting a store would be

> Thank you for your custom

On the other side of the coin, if you're talking about having visited a store and made use of it, would the expression

> Today I gave custom to Store X

be valid? Or is there another expression or word to use ("customed"?)

Comment: Today, I went shopping at ...

Answer (score 1):

> [**patronize**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patronisation)
>    To go to as a customer, especially on a regular basis:
>    *We patronize the local diner.*

The "regular" implication is obviously irrelevant in OP's exact context, because of ***today***. Note that the shopkeeper could have said *"Thank you for your **patronage**"*

Comment: What exactly did you mean by *the shopkeeper/patron*? In French the boss man/woman of an enterprise is *le/la patron(e)*. But in English we rarely use *patron* to mean shopkeeper. The *patrons* of an establishment are the customers, as evidenced by the once typical car park sign which says *Parking for patrons only*.

Comment: @WS2: I just included that usage in a spirit of whimsy. In fact, I'd only use *patron* (short 'a', stress on second syllable) for the owner of a restaurant, where I might still be a *patron* (stress on the initial long 'a'). (But given we're on the *learners'* site, perhaps I'd better edit it out! :)

Comment: Who says we are on the learners' site?

Comment: @WS2: Oops! I admit get them mixed up sometimes.

Comment: I have to say this is a new one on me. I don't recall anyone ever, in England, referring to a restaurateur as a *p'**tron***!